# Sed delete everything between 2 patterns, but not including the patterns

Tags: bash, sed, bsd

I have found a few examples on this, but none that work exactly how I would like.

I would like to delete everything between 1 and several other possible patterns, but not including the patterns themselves.  The pattern pairs are per line only, not across multiple lines.

eg

```
:1543453 Brown Fox
:789 123456 Cat
:abcdef Yellow Duck
```

to

```
:Brown Fox
:Cat
:Yellow Duck
```

So the first pattern to match is the ":" and the second being "Brown" OR "Cat" OR "Yellow"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's brute force and ignorance, which works well on occasion:

```
sed -e 's/^:.* Brown/:Brown/' \
    -e 's/^:.* Cat/:Cat/' \
    -e 's/^:.* Yellow/:Yellow/' \
    data-file.txt
```

You might be able to use 'extended regular expressions' with the `-E` (BSD, Mac, Linux) or `-r` (Linux only) options:

```
sed -E 's/^:.* (Brown|Cat|Yellow)/:\1/' data-file.txt
```

Both produce the desired output on the sample data.

Note that the `.*` used is 'greedy'.  Given the input file:

```
:1543453 Brown Fox
:789 123456 Cat
:abcdef Yellow Duck
:quantum mechanics eat Yellow Ducks for being yellow (but leave Yellow Dafodils alone)
```

both the scripts produce:

```
:Brown Fox
:Cat
:Yellow Duck
:Yellow Dafodils alone)
```

You'd need Perl or a `sed` enhanced with PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions), or some other program, to avoid the greediness.  For example:

```
$ perl -n -e 'print if s/^:.*? (Brown|Cat|Yellow)/:\1/' data-file.txt
:Brown Fox
:Cat
:Yellow Duck
:Yellow Ducks for being yellow (but leave Yellow Dafodils alone)
$
```

Comment: I'm not sure the patterns are fixed. Perhaps use `pat1=":";pat2="(Cat|Yellow|Brown)";sed -r "s/(${pat1}).*(${pat2})/\1\2/" inputfile`

Comment: @WalterA: There are infinitely many similar possibilities for what is intended in the long term.  I dealt with the question posed because trying to guess which alternatives are relevant is too problematic for comfort.  Getting the quoting right around regexes as arguments is tricky, but doable with care.  (Yes, repeating the `:` in the replacement patterns is not necessarily the best technique; using a capture and referencing it in the replacement is more general.

Comment: You can acoid the greediness (when pattern2 is after pattern1) with `sed -E 's/(Brown|Cat|Yellow)/\x01\1/; s/^:.*\x01/:/' data-file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am struggling to get this to work. Not sure if it's because i'm in BSD in a bash script. I am new and learning.

Comment: OK.  I tested the fragments I showed on a Mac running macOS 10.13.4 using the Mac (BSD) `sed`.

Comment: This is what I am doing with what you gave me `sed -i '' -E 's/^:.* (Brown|Cat|Yellow)/:\1/' test.txt` and is the test file I have `Some Text: Remove ME Cat` but it doesnt change. Not sure what the `-i ''` is but I've needed it every other time :)

Comment: The `-i ''` option makes it hard to test your results because it hacks the data file in situ.  It is counter-productive until you've got your `sed` script working — then it saves you writing the output to a temporary file and copying that back over the original.

Comment: The rest of the trouble is that `^` means 'start of line' — in your original data, the colon was always at the start of the line, so I put the anchor in place to prevent lines like the one you're now trying to change from being changed accidentally.  Remove the caret (`^`) and you should be back to where you wanted to be.

Comment: From what I understand it just means edit the file directly, which is what I want. I understand what you mean but since nothing is happening I guess it's not an issue.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I should have known about the ^. Its late here but sorted now. Much thanks

Comment: Until you have the script working, you don't want to risk your valuable data by carelessness.  Also, you don't get to see the result.  Don't use `-i ''` until you know the script does precisely what you want it to do.  Or, if you want it put another way — Please listen to the voice of experience (30+ years of experience) and avoid damaging your data files by accident because it is very easy to make mistakes.  Adding `-i ''` is the last step — when everything else is known to work beautifully.

Comment: Ok thanks I will remember that. All files I'm playing with are test files, so I'm not  _that_ stupid :)